# How to show local branches also found on remote?

Tags: git, git-branch

With `git branch -vv`, we can easily see if the branches have their upstream set. So far, so good. But how can we tell git to list only the matching branches? Or only those only found locally? Like you can list only local branches or only remotes.

Note that the matching list would have to filter out the cases when the remote has been deleted. For example, if we have

```
  featureA  SHA_1 [origin/featureA: gone] Commit message for featureA
  featureB  SHA_1 Commit message for featureB
  featureC  SHA_1 [origin/featureC] Commit message for featureC
* master    SHA_1 [origin/master] Commit message for master
```

it should list featureC and master branches.

Some background. I use the git console, and my team uses topic branches. Sometimes we collaborate on these topic branches, so we push them to the main repository (Github). It would be nice to verify that they have the feature branch(es) we want to collaborate on available, without seeing all remote branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git remote show origin` will list, in the `Local branch configured for 'git pull'` section, all the local branches that are tracking a remote branch. Something like:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <repo_url>
  Push  URL: <repo_url>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    test                   tracked
    foo                    tracked
    2.2.1                  tracked
    master                 tracked
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    foo_2.2.1 merges with remote 2.2.1
    master    merges with remote master
```

Comment: It could work. With my example i also get featureA in the 'git pull' section, but not in the 'git push'. So does it depend on me remembering to unset upstream on featureA?

Comment: @Sten-Åke Probably you did only a `fetch`. To untrack the branch you can use: `git config --unset branch.<local-branch-name>.remote` and `git config --unset branch.<local-branch-name>.merge`.